# Alternate Application subclass for debug build in Android

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, dagger

In an effort to limit debug code from making its way into my release APK, I'm attempting to use a `DebugMyApplication` subclass for debug builds, but the normal `MyApplication` class in release.

Is it possible to use an alternate `Application` subclass in Debug vs Release builds? I've tried:

1. Define An AndroidManifest.xml file in the root of src/debug with an alternate definition of the `<application>` element. Gradle warns me that Main manifest has X but library has Y and the `DebugMyApplication` isn't used.
2. Declare the Application subclass's fully qualified name as a resource which can be defined separately in my debug res files, but `<application android:name="@string/xyz"/>` is interpreted as a literal package name instead of a reference.

---

For some background on my broader goal:

Provide an alternate Dagger module which supplies some static mocked web service responses that will not be found in the release APK. Subclassing my application's `getModuleList()` method and changing the module list declaration seemed like the best bet.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't the answer for the Application overriding but I propose a solution for your broader goal:

```
|-- src
|   +-- debug
|       +-- java
|           +-- mypackage
|               +-- Modules.java
|               +-- MockModule.java
|   +-- main
|       +-- java
|           +-- mypackage
|               +-- MainModule.java
|   +-- release
|       +-- java
|           +-- mypackage
|               +-- Modules.java
```

**src/debug/java/mypackage/Modules.java**

```
public final class Modules {

  public static List<Object> getModules(App application) {
    ArrayList<Object> modules = new ArrayList<Object>();
    modules.add(new MainModule(application));
    modules.add(new MockModule());
    return modules;
  }
}
```

**src/debug/java/mypackage/MockModule.java**

```
@Module(
    overrides = true,
    library = true,
    injects = { MainActivity.class })
public class MockModule {

  @Provides MyType buildMock() {
    return //...
  }
}
```

**src/release/java/mypackage/Modules.java**

```
public final class Modules {

  public static List<Object> getModules(App application) {
    ArrayList<Object> modules = new ArrayList<Object>();
    modules.add(new MainModule(application));
    return modules;
  }
}
```

**src/main/java/mypackage/App.java**

```
public class App extends Application {

  private ObjectGraph graph;

  @Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    graph = ObjectGraph.create(Modules.getModules(this).toArray());
  }

  public void inject(Object object) {
    graph.inject(object);
  }
}
```

Let me know if it works for you.

This technique was presented by Jake Wharton in his [Android Apps with Dagger](https://speakerdeck.com/jakewharton/android-apps-with-dagger) presentation

Comment: Fantastic! This was just the kind of redirection I thought I might be needing. This works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an Application subclass for your debug type by creating a MyDebugApplication class and adding it to the DEBUG source folder, and setting

```
<application
    android:name="com.example.MyDebugApplication"
    tools:replace="android:name">
</application>
```

as the application tag in your AndroidManifest.xml file in the DEBUG source folder.

If you already have a Application subclass, MyApplication, in your main source set, you can make MyDebugApplication extend MyApplication.